# C++ Nested loops for beginner. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I've tried various edits but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

I want each year to look similar to the following; however, it doesn't seem to work for the first and last years (only all the ones in between):

At an interest rate of 11%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Year  1: $1120.00

Year  2: $1254.40

Year  3: $1404.93

Year  4: $1573.52

Year  5: $1762.34

Year  6: $1973.82

Year  7: $2210.68

Year  8: $2475.96

Year  9: $2773.08

Year 10: $3105.85

Please help!

```
int main()
    {
    int interest, year;
    double amount;
    for (interest=6; interest <= 12; interest++)            //start of outer loop
    {
        amount = 1000;
        for (year=1; year <= 10; year++)                        // start of inner loop
        {
            amount = amount + interest * .01 * amount;
            cout << "End of year " << setw(2) << year << ": $" 
                 << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << amount << endl;
        }                                                           // end of inner for loop

        cout << "\nAt an interest rate of " << interest
         << "%, the amount of money available at the end\n"
         << "of the first ten years is as follows: \n" ;
    }                                                               // end of outer for loop
    return 0;
}
```

-----------output-----------

Year  1: $1060.00
Year  2: $1123.60
Year  3: $1191.02
Year  4: $1262.48
Year  5: $1338.23
Year  6: $1418.52
Year  7: $1503.63
Year  8: $1593.85
Year  9: $1689.48
Year 10: $1790.85

At an interest rate of 6%, the amount of money available at the end
of the first ten years is as follows:
Year  1: $1070.00
Year  2: $1144.90
Year  3: $1225.04
Year  4: $1310.80
Year  5: $1402.55
Year  6: $1500.73
Year  7: $1605.78
Year  8: $1718.19
Year  9: $1838.46
Year 10: $1967.15

At an interest rate of 7%, the amount of money available at the end
of the first ten years is as follows:
Year  1: $1080.00
Year  2: $1166.40
Year  3: $1259.71
Year  4: $1360.49
Year  5: $1469.33
Year  6: $1586.87
Year  7: $1713.82
Year  8: $1850.93
Year  9: $1999.00
Year 10: $2158.92

At an interest rate of 8%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Year  1: $1090.00

Year  2: $1188.10

Year  3: $1295.03

Year  4: $1411.58

Year  5: $1538.62

Year  6: $1677.10

Year  7: $1828.04

Year  8: $1992.56

Year  9: $2171.89

Year 10: $2367.36

At an interest rate of 9%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Year  1: $1100.00

Year  2: $1210.00

Year  3: $1331.00

Year  4: $1464.10

Year  5: $1610.51

Year  6: $1771.56

Year  7: $1948.72

Year  8: $2143.59

Year  9: $2357.95

Year 10: $2593.74

At an interest rate of 10%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Year  1: $1110.00

Year  2: $1232.10

Year  3: $1367.63

Year  4: $1518.07

Year  5: $1685.06

Year  6: $1870.41

Year  7: $2076.16

Year  8: $2304.54

Year  9: $2558.04

Year 10: $2839.42

At an interest rate of 11%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Year  1: $1120.00

Year  2: $1254.40

Year  3: $1404.93

Year  4: $1573.52

Year  5: $1762.34

Year  6: $1973.82

Year  7: $2210.68

Year  8: $2475.96

Year  9: $2773.08

Year 10: $3105.85

At an interest rate of 12%, the amount of money available at the end

of the first ten years is as follows:

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Move the cout outside the inner loop

Comment: Your question is too long. Narrow it down please!

Comment: I've tried moving them all around and I don't get the output I want. Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Orbit, do you mean that I shouldn't post the output? I was only trying to be thorough.

Comment: @Orbit I disagree. The output data and the code are important for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int interest, year;
    double amount;

    for (interest=6; interest <= 12; interest++)            //start of outer loop
    {

         cout << "\nAt an interest rate of " << interest
             << "%, the amount of money available at the end\n"
             << "of the first ten years is as follows: \n" ;

         amount = 1000;

         for (year=1; year <= 10; year++)                        // start of inner loop
         {

            amount = amount + interest * .01 * amount;
            cout << "End of year " << setw(2) << year << ": $" 
                  << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << amount << endl;

         }                                                           // end of inner for loop

     }                                                               // end of outer for loop

     return 0;

}
```

What occurs is that in this code the loop displays the "At an interest rate..." statement **before** it displays the actual data. In your code the displaying statements were reversed.

Comment: That worked! I'm close to understanding it and after a few more exercises, I'll have it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If you need any more help, feel free to post more questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its working for the other interest rates, but it isn't. For example the numbers after the 7% text are actually the numbers for 8%. The reason for this is that the text beginning 'At an interest' is being generated after the inner loop, you need to move that bit to before the for loop that goes through the years.